# Division is incorect in java

Tags: java, floating-point, division

I'am confused. I'm trying to get an `int` value:

```
Integer ord = new Double(33 / (-2 * 1.1)).intValue();
```

Expectation: -15
Output: -14

What's wrong?

When I try:

```
Double d = 33 / (-2 * 1.1);
```

Output: `-14.999999999999998`

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's close enough. Welcome to floating point arithmetic. If you want to round use Math.round() not .intValue()

Comment: If I had a nickel for every time I heard this, I'd probably have 45 cents.

Comment: Integer ord = Math.round(new Float(33 / (-2 * 1.1)));

Comment: This question gets asked very (very) often. Please take some time and search next time.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to stackoverflow. Will search next time better.

Comment: Don't use `Double` or `Integer` unless you have to.  `double` and `int` are not only simpler but much faster.

Comment: @pcnThird If I had a nickel for every time I heard this, I'd proabbably have 44.99987 cents.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`.intValue()` will trunc the frarctinal part so you can use [`Math.ceil()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#ceil%28double%29), [`Math.floor()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#floor%28double%29) or you can use [`Math.round()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#round%28double%29) to approximate it to the nearest value

```
Integer result = (int) Math.round(new Double(33/(-2*1.1))); //-15
Integer result = (int) Math.floor(new Double(33/(-2*1.1))); //-15
Integer result = (int) Math.ceil(new Double(33/(-2*1.1)));  //-14
```

You can see that `Math.ceil()` give us 14 because this is a negative number -14>-15 so the ceil of -14.9999 is -14  and the inverse apply on Math.floor()

Comment: It depends on what Zanas_x3 wants but I'd say `Math.round()` is probably more what he expects than `Math.ceil()`.

Comment: Thanks! I need to trunc, because I expect such results:

  Integer ord = new Double(32 / (-2 * 1.1)).intValue(); //-14
  Integer ord = new Double(33 / (-2 * 1.1)).intValue(); //-15
  Integer ord = new Double(34 / (-2 * 1.1)).intValue(); //-15

Answer (score 1):

`intValue()` doesn't do round but truncate.

Answer (score 1):

The double output of -14.999999999999998 has it's origin in the precision of the double type. A floating point number is always a sum of `2^n` numbers. The result is that not all numbers can be represented precisely, even with double.

Your integer example returns -14 because the integer value of -14.999999999999998 is -14. There is no rounding when getting the integer value. It is just cut of at the decimal point.

For rounding use either [`Math.ceil()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#ceil%28double%29) for rounding up, [`Math.floor()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#floor%28double%29) for rounding down or [`Math.round()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#round%28double%29) for general rounding.

Answer (score 1):

When getting the int value of a double, java isn't doing any round up or down for you. It just omits the decimals.

What you want to do is to use the Math.round(double) to get the value you are expecting.

I believe the java doc for Math.round() says it will return a long value, but if you are sure that your result never will be larger than the maximum int value, then you can cast it to an int.

```
 int result = (int) Math.round(new Double(33/(-2*1.1)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Warning: Using the authority argument :P

Josh Bloch has an entire item in his Effective Java book against using `double` or `float` when aiming for accuracy.  In my life, working with currency, for example, I have had the best results working with `BigDecimal`

Answer (score 0):

You are using 32 bit float so losing a lot of precision. Try `Double d = 33 / (-2 * 1.1d)`;
And, as everybody say, better round than truncate.